# Why is it only 5 reputation points for an up vote on a question?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, reputation, votes

I would have thought that it should be the same as it is for answers. A good question is just as important as a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question upvotes used to award 10 points. That was changed last year. From [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/):

> question upvotes will now grant only +5 rep instead of +10.* There is no change to answer upvotes. This will apply retroactively to all >users.
>
> Why?
>
> - While we value good questions (and
>   asking a great question is absolutely
>   an art), we want to explicitly
>   encourage people to provide the best
>   possible answers. Without people
>   interested in providing good answers,
>   the questions are moot. We know that
>   answers have more intrinsic value than
>   questions, and the reputation balance
>   should reflect that.
> - The question
>   asker already enjoys a substantial
>   benefit beyond reputation gain from
>   upvotes on their question — namely,
>   they get great answers to their
>   question! Thus, the asker shouldn’t
>   need as much reputation gain.
> - There
>   are a few users who ask hundreds,
>   sometimes even thousands of questions.
>   Over time, these users generate a
>   fairly sizable reputation entirely
>   through the tiny trickle of upvotes
>   gained by these questions. In a sense,
>   we want to discourage question asking
>   a little bit, and make sure that
>   people who ask questions are doing it
>   for the right reasons and not to
>   generate reputation.

See also this [discussion post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced) on Meta.SO.